# Is there a maximum number of entries for the Navigation Editing and Sorting control?

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, navigation

Is there an upper limit to the number of item that are displayed in the Navigation Editing and Sorting control in the ‘Site Navigation Settings’ page?

I have 49 items in the global Navigation and 54 items in the Current Navigation (most of which are hidden). I’ve added a new page to the pages library and I’d like to hide it from the navigation menu, however it’s not showing in the Navigation Editing and Sorting control.

This made me wonder if there was an upper limit to the number of items that are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this... http://slightlyrational.com/extending-the-50-site-limit-in-sharepoints-site-directory/

> It basically boils down to adding a property **`DynamicChildLimit="XX"`** to the following entries in the `siteMap` `providers` section of the web.config file, where `XX` is `0` (no limit) or whatever numeric limit you decide. By default it is – you guessed it – `50`.
>
> (The web.config file to modify is usually located in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80`, with the last portion being whatever port number MOSS is running from):

```
<siteMap ...>
<providers>
<add name="GlobalNavSiteMapProvider" description="CMS provider for Global navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Global" EncodeOutput="true" DynamicChildLimit="0" />
<add name="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider" description="CMS provider for Combined navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Combined" EncodeOutput="true" DynamicChildLimit="0" />
<add name="CurrentNavSiteMapProvider" description="CMS provider for Current navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Current" EncodeOutput="true" DynamicChildLimit="0" />
<add name="CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode" description="CMS provider for Current navigation, no encoding of output" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Current" EncodeOutput="false" DynamicChildLimit="0" />
</providers>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: you beauty! that fixedi it.

Answer (score 1):

By default limit of the Site Map provider is 50.  We can set as much as we want.  If you want to set no limit then add 0.  You need to open web.config of your site and add the poperty DynamicChildLimit="XX"  inside the following 4 providers.

**GlobalNavSiteMapProvider,
CombinedNavSiteMapProvider,
CurrentNavSiteMapProvider,
CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode**

Also you need to set the Maximum number of dynamic items as 0 Under the Current Navigation section under the Navigation settings.

For more details please have a look of the link http://blog.prosares.com/?p=20